# Метод замены элемента в массиве

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив

```
[
  {  
    "name":"BMW",
    "price":"55 000",
    "color":"red",
 },
 {  
   "name":"MERSEDEC",
   "price":"63 000",
   "color":"blue",
 }
];
```

Нужно написать функцию которая будет на входе принимать массив и на выходе будет вместо name  будет вылетать class

```
"class":"MERSEDEC",
"price":"63 000",
"color":"blue",
```

Какой метод использовать?

Comment: а где `marka` ?

Comment: Сорри , исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если почему-либо требуется оставить исходный массив в первозданном виде:

```js
let data = [{
    "name": "BMW",
    "price": "55 000",
    "color": "red",
  },
  {

    "name": "MERSEDEC",
    "price": "63 000",
    "color": "blue",
  }
];

function transform(arr) {
  return arr.map(item => {
    let newItem = Object.assign({}, item);
    newItem.class = item.name;
    delete newItem.name;
    return newItem;
  })
}

console.log(transform(data));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "BMW",
    "price": "55 000",
    "color": "red",
  },
  {
    "name": "MERSEDEC",
    "price": "63 000",
    "color": "blue",
  }
];
function nameToClass(arr) {
  arr.forEach(i => {
    i.class = i.name;
    delete i.name;
  });
  return arr;
}
console.log(nameToClass(data));
```

> Как сделать так что бы class был первым, а не в конце?

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "BMW",
    "price": "55 000",
    "color": "red",
  },
  {
    "name": "MERSEDEC",
    "price": "63 000",
    "color": "blue",
  }
];
function nameToClass(arr) {
  var str = JSON.stringify(arr);
  str = str.replace(/name/g, "class");
  arr.splice(0, arr.length, ...JSON.parse(str));
  return arr;
}
console.log(nameToClass(data));
```

Comment: Object {price: "55 000", color: "red", class: "BMW"} вот что выводит . Как сделать так что бы class был первым, а не в конце?

Comment: @LoveGIAS Зачем?

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно заменить `name` на `class`, то можно просто сделать всё в цикле:

```
var items; // Ваш массив с данными.
var i;
for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    items[i].class = items[i].name;
    delete items[i].name;
}
```

Comment: Нужно использывать метод